How to fix post API?
I have 2 models with the following relationship and when I want to create an API post for the first model, it gives an error:
 public class PositionGroup
 {
     [Key]
     public int IdPoGr { get; set; }

     [Required, MaxLength(150)]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Position>? positions { get; set; }
 }

public class Position
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPos { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(150)]
    public string PositionName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PositionGroup")]
    public int IdPosGr {  get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public PositionGroup? positionGroup { get; set; }
}

When executing the post method:
{
  "idPoGr": 0,
  "name": "G1",
  "positions": [
    {
      "idPos": 0,
      "positionName": "string",
      "idPosGr": 0,
      "createDate": "2024-10-02T05:17:13.314Z",
      "positionGroup": "string"
    }
  ]
}

I have an error:
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-3b028362a6c027c0b63aa86cfee53628-50a135cc3612d607-00",
  "errors": {
    "positionGroup": [
      "The positionGroup field is required."
    ],
    "$.positions[0].positionGroup": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to API_CDE.Models.PositionGroup. Path: $.positions[0].positionGroup | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 31."
    ]
  }
}

How can I fix it? Please help.Thank you
I don't know how to fix it because this is the first time I have to move from .NET 5 to .NET 6

Looking at the code it looks like you are trying to use your EF models as a parameter to your API Post endpoint, which is not good practice and this is the main reason which is causing the issue, because to maintain the relation between your Parent and Child model you have added parent reference into the child model and it's creating circular reference.
So to fix this create separate models for accepting input values from the user.

In your request you sent positionGroup object as a string value. You have a specific error that says that provided value can't be converted into API_CDE.Models.PositionGroup object.
"$.positions[0].positionGroup": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to API_CDE.Models.PositionGroup. Path: $.positions[0].positionGroup | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 31."
    ]

As I see your code, you have 2 domain models with parent-child relationship. You need to remove positionGroup from your http post request. Since that you don't have to mention your parent object inside the child component.
Update your request to:
{
  "idPoGr": 0,
  "name": "G1",
  "positions": [
    {
      "idPos": 0,
      "positionName": "string",
      "idPosGr": 0,
      "createDate": "2024-10-02T05:17:13.314Z"
    }
  ]
}


This error "$.positions[0].positionGroup": [
"The JSON value could not be converted to API_CDE.Models.PositionGroup. Path: $.positions[0].positionGroup | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 31."
] simply comes when it cannot define the model or the table so the simple issue is that it cannot be converted into this data type. when your inserting the data just make sure to assign the values to model properly and then insert the data and try.

I can reproduce your issue in my side, I created a web api and use [FromBody] PositionGroup group as the input parameter, then I trust you have the same result. Swashbuckle can't help generate a correct request body for us.

In your senario, PositionGroup has a collection of Position, and each Position refers back to its parent PositionGroup which creating a circular reference when trying to serialize/deserialize JSON. We can definetely remove positionGroup from your http post request just like Jivopis, but what I want to add here is using [JsonIgnore] above public PositionGroup? PositionGroup. JsonIgnore attribtue helps ignore individual properties and specify conditional exclusion.
By the way, create models like what you shared are good for ensuring referential integrity(each Position referres back to its parent PositionGroup via a foreign key), but for API response, I'm afraid it's not necessary to keep the relationship so that we can use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) like below and only used it in API response for serialize/deserialize purpose.
public class PositionGroupDTO
{
    public int IdPoGr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PositionDTO> Positions { get; set; }
}

public class PositionDTO
{
    public int IdPos { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

